# SQL Azure managed instance and BCP connection

Tags: azure-sql-database, bcp

I am trying to import a file with BCP into Azure SQL managed instance with the following code:

I have changed the user, password, and database string below for security purposes.

```
BCP [donsdatabase].[dbo].[TEMP_DELIVERIES_NEW] IN C:\dogfishworking\bcpfiles\temp_deliveries.txt -S donsonlinedb.public.98858787.database.windows.net,3342; -U databaseuser@donsonlinedb.public.98858787 -P donspassword -c
```

I continue to get the error that I cannot login:
Login failed for user 'databaseuser@donsonlinedb.public.98858787'

Does anyone know how to connect with BCP to Azure SQL instance?
My assumption is that the user is not formatted properly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows:

```
BCP [donsdatabase].[dbo].[TEMP_DELIVERIES_NEW] IN C:\dogfishworking\bcpfiles\temp_deliveries.txt -S donsonlinedb.public.98858787.database.windows.net,3342; -U databaseuser -P donspassword -c
```